# How can I allow to read a file only if you are trying to read it from a specific page?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to deny the access to some json files (for example, opening in the browser mysite.com/files/name.json have to return an error 403), but I want to allow a specific page to read these json files in a javascript fetch function.

So I put an .htaccess in the folder where the json files are contained, and I tried to write this:

```
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Jj][Ss][Oo][Nn])">
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ^/lab/app/maker.js
</Files>
```

But it doesn't work and return an error 500. How can I say something like "allow to read these files if the page that are trying to read is maker.js"?

Comment: What do you mean by "from a specific path"? If a referer is set?

Comment: I mean a specific page. I want to allow only to maker.js to read the files. And deny to read them in other situations (for example deny to read them if you write their path in a browser).